# Dynamic sub-domain handling with python Flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, digital-ocean

I have just setup nginx+ uWSGI for my flask application from tutorial provided by [vladikk](http://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/) and now I need to configure my server to handle **dynamic sub-domains** like - user1.example.com, user2.example.com.

I am totally novice about server configuration. I don't know how to go about this configuration as there are no appropriate guidance available on internet and I also have doubt whether there is any setup needed from digitalOcean DNS Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic sub-domains generally use a named capture in the `server_name` directive, which can then be used parameterise other directives, such as `root`, `access_log` and `error_log`. For example:

```
server {
  listen ...;
  server_name ~^(?<subsystem>.+)\.example\.com$;
  root        /path/to/root/$subsystem;
  access_log /path/to/logs/$subsystem-access.log;
  error_log /path/to/logs/$subsystem-error.log info;
  ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.